# Visual Studio 2015 is not auto completing Unity keywords

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity and I had no problem in using Visual Studio as my default editor in Unity, however I've noticed that Unity's keywords and methods do not auto complete, only the VS do.

For example: `GetComponent<>`, or `OnGui()` and `Input.GetMouseButton`, these are specifically from Unity, when I was using MonoDevelop it displayed the available options of methods when I was typing `Input.GetMouse`... and if I clicked CTRL + Space it auto completed.

I would like to know if is there any way that I can make Visual Studio recognize Unity API.
Since I am new in Unity and C# I don't know if this is a default behavior, if I should set up something to enable this auto complete feature or if something is wrong and it should be working and somehow it is not.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note, make sure you read the tag descriptions for the tags you are using, unity is for Microsoft Unity IOC framework, unity3d is for the game development engine.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad =X Thanks for the tip @RonBeyer

Comment: It means that your namespace is not included, that is why VS can't use the Intellisense for the methods member of Unity3D. Open the SLN instead of the C# file so It will open the entire project that usually the Unity3D will create for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import Unity VS Tools' package into unity, open visual studio and use Ctrl-Shift-Q to call Quick MonoBehavior Wizard
Configure Shortcuts: http://unityvs.com/documentation/shortcuts/
Good luck

Comment: I don't know what I've done wrong so I removed and installed Visual Studio again and it worked perfectly well. I believe it must have been some error during instalation. Thank you very much for your answer though.